# How do I refresh/update a LongListSelector after removing a MenuItem (on Windows Phone 8)?

Tags: windows-phone-8, refresh, longlistselector

I am trying to delete a MenuItem from a LongListSelector in my Windows Phone 8 app.  The MenuItems play various sounds when clicked and I want the user to be able to delete them.

There are two panels on the app.  The second panel records a new sound and puts the recording on the LongListSelector as a new MenuItem.

Problem: After I do the delete the display looks exactly the same and the sound still plays! However, if I record a new sound (switching to the new recording panel) then the deletion works with the deleted MenuItem gone.

How do I force the update/refresh of the LongListSelector to unload/delete the MenuItem and associated sound data resident on the GUI?

The following code is called from from the MenuItem's click event.  The LongListSelector is named 'CustomSounds':

```
private void DeleteSoundClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem == null) return;

    var soundData = menuItem.DataContext as SoundData;
    if (soundData == null) return; 

    if (soundData.FilePath.Contains(CustomSounds.Name))
    {
        CustomSounds.ItemsSource.Remove(soundData);
    }

    this.LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inverse your thing. Set item source with new list.

```
private void DeleteSoundClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem == null) return;

    var soundData = menuItem.DataContext as SoundData;
    if (soundData == null) return; 

    if (soundData.FilePath.Contains(CustomSounds.Name))
    {
        MyNewList.remove(soundData);
        CustomSounds.ItemsSource = myNewList;
    }

    this.LayoutRoot.UpdateLayout();
}
```

Create local variable and set your itemsource in constructor.

Other thing :

create an updated list :

```
private ObservableCollection<Sound> _myNewList;
public ObservableCollection<Sound> MynewList{
get
  {
    return _myNewList;
  }
  set
  {
    _myNewList= value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(MynewList); 
   }
```

Bind this in your listbox :

```
<listbox itemSource="{Binding MyNewList" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSound,mode=twoway}>
```

Create selectedSound:

```
private Sound _selectedSound;
public Sound SelectedSound{
get
  {
    return _selectedSound;
  }
  set
  {
    _selectedSound= value;
    RaisePropertyChanged(SelectedSound); 
   }
```

Delete item :

```
private void DeleteSoundClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(SelectedSound != null){
Mynewlist.remove(SelectedSound);
}

}
```

:D

Comment: Very nice - treat the UI like it is immutable and let the garbage collector clean up.

But I'm a little confused by your use of ObservableCollection.  I previously tried to use ObservableCollection instead of LongListSelector and it failed to compile.  Maybe I missed the right place to put the ObservableCollection?

Comment: ObservableCollection<T> implements INotifyCollectionChanged which provides notification when the collection is changed. It allows the binding engine to update the UI when the ObservableCollection is updated.

LongListSelector is like textblock.It's component in your xaml.

<ObervableCollection></ObservableCollection> don't exist :)
<LongListSelector itemSource="{Binding YourObservableCollection}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSound,mode=twoway"}/>

Comment: I'm trying to use your solution but doesn't work.. first of all RaisePropertyChanged is not valid on that context, where do you have declared it? Also, do you tried this solution on LongListSelector? please help!!! @MatDev8

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection is nothing more than a collection with notification that when something is changed in the collection, it lets the UI know.  It's just a ItemSource, so your LongListSelector is populated by the OC...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, however, I used simple List.

Solution was easy - just created new object of the List

```
var newList = new List<TheModel>();

newList.AddRange(originalList);

TheLongListSelector.ItemsSource = newList;
TheLongListSelector.UpdateLayout();
```

originalList was list with removed item.

It's not the most efficient way, but it works. I think that's no problem for small data.