# How to refresh LongListSelector after delete an item

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector like that

```
<phone:LongListSelector Name="ListRecentFiles"
                                        LayoutMode="Grid"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                        GridCellSize="140,140"
                                        SelectionChanged="ListRecentFiles_SelectionChanged">

                        <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Background="Red" Margin="0,0,5,5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NoteTitle}" Style="{Binding PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                                            <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Delete" Header="Delete" Click="DeleteNote_Click" />
                                        </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    </phone:LongListSelector>
```

this is DataContext: `public static ObservableCollection<Note> NoteItems;`

And i try to delete an item from LongListSelector

```
private void DeleteNote_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Note selectedNote = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Note;
    ListRecentFiles.ItemsSource.Remove(item);
    NoteItems.Remove(selectedNote);
}
```

It's not work except i navigate to a other XAML page and return

I have visited this page but can't fix [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659395/how-do-i-refresh-update-a-longlistselector-after-removing-a-menuitem-on-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing more of the code, it's hard to be sure what's going wrong.  But if you are setting

```
ListRecentFiles.DataContext = NoteItems;
```

that is incorrect.  You want to set

```
ListRecentFiles.ItemsSource = NoteItems;
```

The XAML declaration:

```
ItemSource="{Binding}"
```

Could do that (depending on the rest of the code).  Once .ItemsSource is set correctly, then the line:

```
NoteItems.Remove(selectedNote);
```

Should succeed in removing the visual item from the LongListSelector. In any case, you should not do the line:

```
ListRecentFiles.ItemsSource.Remove(item);
```

That would do the wrong thing when the list gets so big that it doesn't all fit in memory at once.

Comment: I have set `DataContent = NoteItems;` and LongListSelector display correctly. I'm finding the way to remove an item without leave current xaml page

Comment: thank, i solved it. Just set `ListRecentFiles.ItemSource = NoteItems;`